# FileNotFoundError when trying to upload a local file to S3 through Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Full disclosure: I'm relatively new to the AWS world. As the title states, I'm trying to upload a folder from my local machine to an amazon S3 volume, via JupyterLab in Sagemaker studio. I'm able to manually do this by clicking the [upload icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTzyt.png) in JupyterLab, but I'm hoping to be able to do it with the following syntax:

```py
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tuner import (
    IntegerParameter,
    CategoricalParameter,
    ContinuousParameter,
    HyperparameterTuner,
)

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
region = sagemaker_session.boto_region_name
bucket = sagemaker_session.default_bucket()
prefix = "sagemaker/my-first-proj"
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

local_dir = "/Users/tomi/DevProjects/WeThePeople/datasets"
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path=local_dir, bucket=bucket, key_prefix=prefix)
```

When I run the code block above, this is the error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 local_dir = "/Users/tomi/DevProjects/WeThePeople/datasets"
----> 2 inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path=local_dir, bucket=bucket, key_prefix=prefix)
      3 print("input spec (in this case, just an S3 path): {}".format(inputs))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py:400, in Session.upload_data(self, path, bucket, key_prefix, extra_args)
    397     s3 = self.s3_resource
    399 for local_path, s3_key in files:
--> 400     s3.Object(bucket, s3_key).upload_file(local_path, ExtraArgs=extra_args)
    402 s3_uri = "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket, key_prefix)
    403 # If a specific file was used as input (instead of a directory), we return the full S3 key
    404 # of the uploaded object. This prevents unintentionally using other files under the same
    405 # prefix during training.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py:318, in object_upload_file(self, Filename, ExtraArgs, Callback, Config)
    287 def object_upload_file(
    288     self, Filename, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None
    289 ):
    290     """Upload a file to an S3 object.
    291 
    292     Usage::
   (...)
    316         transfer.
    317     """
--> 318     return self.meta.client.upload_file(
    319         Filename=Filename,
    320         Bucket=self.bucket_name,
    321         Key=self.key,
    322         ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs,
    323         Callback=Callback,
    324         Config=Config,
    325     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py:143, in upload_file(self, Filename, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs, Callback, Config)
    108 """Upload a file to an S3 object.
    109 
    110 Usage::
   (...)
    140     transfer.
    141 """
    142 with S3Transfer(self, Config) as transfer:
--> 143     return transfer.upload_file(
    144         filename=Filename,
    145         bucket=Bucket,
    146         key=Key,
    147         extra_args=ExtraArgs,
    148         callback=Callback,
    149     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py:292, in S3Transfer.upload_file(self, filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args)
    288 future = self._manager.upload(
    289     filename, bucket, key, extra_args, subscribers
    290 )
    291 try:
--> 292     future.result()
    293 # If a client error was raised, add the backwards compatibility layer
    294 # that raises a S3UploadFailedError. These specific errors were only
    295 # ever thrown for upload_parts but now can be thrown for any related
    296 # client error.
    297 except ClientError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py:103, in TransferFuture.result(self)
     98 def result(self):
     99     try:
    100         # Usually the result() method blocks until the transfer is done,
    101         # however if a KeyboardInterrupt is raised we want want to exit
    102         # out of this and propagate the exception.
--> 103         return self._coordinator.result()
    104     except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    105         self.cancel()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py:266, in TransferCoordinator.result(self)
    263 # Once done waiting, raise an exception if present or return the
    264 # final result.
    265 if self._exception:
--> 266     raise self._exception
    267 return self._result

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py:269, in SubmissionTask._main(self, transfer_future, **kwargs)
    265     self._transfer_coordinator.set_status_to_running()
    267     # Call the submit method to start submitting tasks to execute the
    268     # transfer.
--> 269     self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
    270 except BaseException as e:
    271     # If there was an exception raised during the submission of task
    272     # there is a chance that the final task that signals if a transfer
   (...)
    281 
    282     # Set the exception, that caused the process to fail.
    283     self._log_and_set_exception(e)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py:591, in UploadSubmissionTask._submit(self, client, config, osutil, request_executor, transfer_future, bandwidth_limiter)
    589 # Determine the size if it was not provided
    590 if transfer_future.meta.size is None:
--> 591     upload_input_manager.provide_transfer_size(transfer_future)
    593 # Do a multipart upload if needed, otherwise do a regular put object.
    594 if not upload_input_manager.requires_multipart_upload(
    595     transfer_future, config
    596 ):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py:244, in UploadFilenameInputManager.provide_transfer_size(self, transfer_future)
    242 def provide_transfer_size(self, transfer_future):
    243     transfer_future.meta.provide_transfer_size(
--> 244         self._osutil.get_file_size(transfer_future.meta.call_args.fileobj)
    245     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py:247, in OSUtils.get_file_size(self, filename)
    246 def get_file_size(self, filename):
--> 247     return os.path.getsize(filename)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py:50, in getsize(filename)
     48 def getsize(filename):
     49     """Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
---> 50     return os.stat(filename).st_size

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/tomi/DevProjects/WeThePeople/datasets'
```

I know for certain however that this path exists on my machine. If I go into terminal, I'm clearly able to access the directory as seen below:

```
>>> (WeThePeople) tomi@MacBook-Pro-4 datasets % pwd
/Users/tomi/DevProjects/WeThePeople/datasets
```

I thought perhaps this might be an IAM permission thing on AWS, but the user profile I'm using sagemaker with has both `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess`. Not sure if this is the issue but just thought I'd mention.

Question is, what could be causing this issue and how do I resolve it? Could it be some other permissions settings? Is there something else I haven't checked?

Comment: You are missing an initial "/" on `local_dir`, making the path a relative path to wherever you're running, which no doubt doesn't exist.

Comment: I retried it with the leading "/" as you recommended, same error persists. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your studio notebook is not the same as your local machine.

Looking at the command you shared:

```
>>> (WeThePeople) tomi@MacBook-Pro-4 datasets % pwd
/Users/tomi/DevProjects/WeThePeople/datasets
```

This appears to be your your Mac. Studio does not have access to your local Mac files. If you want, you can upload your files to Studio with that upload button you stated and then you will be able to upload them to S3 from SageMaker Studio referring to the path in Studio.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. What was confusing was both stack overflow answers and AWS documentation online refer to your "local directory" but I'm realizing now that means local to AWS...anyways thanks for the help!